# Converting .POST into equivalent .AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to change one of my .post javascript calls to an equivalent .ajax call, but I can't seem to make it work. (I need to make it asynchronous, and the post does not allow that extra option).

The original working .post call is the following:

```
          $.post('includes/save_my_note.php', { pagenum: lastpage, userid: <?php echo $logged_user_id; ?>, subid: <?php echo $snipid; ?>, thenote: mynote, doctype: dtype, fileid: <?php echo $file_id; ?> });
```

It is a combination of javascript variables and inserted php variables, but it works perfectly in my code, calls the function and passes in all the variables via the $_POST variables.

In trying to turn this into the exactly equivalent .ajax call, I turned it into the following:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "includes/save_my_note.php",
            data: "{ pagenum: " +lastpage+ ", userid: <?php echo $logged_user_id; ?>, subid: <?php echo $snipid; ?>, thenote: " +mynote+ ", doctype: " +dtype+ ", fileid: <?php echo $file_id; ?> }"
        });
```

From looking at the .post and .ajax documentation, I think these should be identical in their execution, but it isn't working.

Anyone know the correct syntax to turn my post call into an ajax call?  I must be missing something unless there is more going on behind the scenes than I know.

Comment: `$.post` **is** asynchronous. And the [`$.post` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) gives you the equivalent `$.ajax` call. The difference is that in your `$.post` call, you pass an **object** as `data` and in the `$.ajax` call, you pass a **string**. Why? Just pass the object as you do with `$.post`.

Comment: Did you mean asynchronous or synchronous?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between

```
"{ pagenum: " +lastpage+ ", userid: <?php echo $logged_user_id; ?>, subid: <?php echo $snipid; ?>, thenote: " +mynote+ ", doctype: " +dtype+ ", fileid: <?php echo $file_id; ?> }"
```

and

```
{ pagenum: lastpage, userid: <?php echo $logged_user_id; ?>, subid: <?php echo $snipid; ?>, thenote: mynote, doctype: dtype, fileid: <?php echo $file_id; ?> }
```

is essential here. The former is a string, the latter an object literal. Only the latter will work here. If you want to use a string, you should do it like this

```
data: "pagenum=" + lastpage + "&userid= .....
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my lack of syntax knowledge, I knew I was doing something wrong there.  I went with the post and turning off the async flag temporarily to solve my problem, but I guess I have to brush up on my datastring format syntax knowledge

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` is asynchronous by default. Do you mean you want to make it synchronous?

In that case, don't bother with `$.ajax`. Just call

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

before you call `.post()`. Careful, though: synchronous requests often cause the browser to "lock up", which is quite ugly and scares users. Could a simple loading indicator on an asynchronous request do the trick?

Comment: It's worth noting setting `async` to `false` will often lock up the browser's UI while the POST is being made.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  After 5 hours of trying to figure out how to add the async to an ajax call, that did the trick and solved the problem.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Ben: Making Ajax synchronous is generally a bad idea... try to find an other way first.

Comment: @BenCahan, no problem! Felix Kling pointed out the specific problem with your `$.ajax` call in a comment, but I think this is a nice workaround.

Comment: It is part of an autosave as I have a text box that autosaves when a users scrolls through a document, but that is only triggered on a page change, and I need to save the current contents to the DB when the user leaves the page or it will be lost.  The async change 9and change back afterwards of course) is the perfect solution for me.